# Is it possible to add a SKSpriteNode to a scene from another class?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode, skscene

Is it possible to add a SKSpriteNode to a scene from another class?

*These are examples

So I have a SKScene with a custom class ..

```
class MainMenu: SKScene {

   code...

}
```

And another SKScene with a custom class ..

```
class GameOver: SKScene {

   code...

}
```

I have another class called PopupMenu ...

```
class PopupMenu: SKScene {

    func addSprite() {

    theSprite = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "theImage")
    theSprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2)
    theSprite.zPosition = 2

    self.addChild(theSprite)

}
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to be able to click the show menu button on both the MainMenu Scene and the GameOver Scene and be able to call the function from PopupMenu to add that node to the respective scene.

I can achieve this by writing the code for the popup in each Scene Class but i feel like this is not the best way to do it in terms of reusability.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Look into `SKReferenceNodes`,  you can create your popup menu via the SpriteKit Scene Builder,  then save this as an sks file.  When it comes time to use it, you just pull up the file of the popup menu, and add it to the scene.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skreferencenode

Another thing you can do if you plan on not using the SKS Builder (Which I recommend using because it is just awesome and a huge time saver),  is to subclass your pop up menu as an SKSpriteNode,  not a scene

```
class PopupMenu: SKSpriteNode {

    required init?(coder: aDecoder:NScoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)    
    }    

    override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: SKColor!, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size) {
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(imageNamed: "theImage")
        self.zPosition = 2    
    }


}
```

Then in your scene code, just call

```
let popup = PopupMenu()
popup.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2)
self.addChild(popup)
```

Comment: That's interesting and I've never done that but if I were to do that,  but how would it work then? If it's just an sks file, where would the code for the menu to work come from?

Comment: ... The same place any other code behind is at, you set the Custom Class field on the scene in SKS builder

Comment: I didn't know that because I've only worked with SpriteKit games by code. I don't use the SKS builder since it's so buggy on Xcode 7. It would clear my nodes and sometimes remove everything despite me saving.

Comment: That makes no sense,  this allows you to use the same node on any scene you want, are you against writing `addChild(SKReferenceNode(...))` or something because that is the only code you would be writing

Comment: to make your Popup menu code work with the scene, you call the grandparent inside of your popup menu class code(grandparent because the parent is the reference node)

Comment: you wouldn't be doing all of that addSprite code either,  your popup menu will already be created

Comment: I made an alternative for you

Comment: what method are we talking about

Comment: actually, the answer is the same for both,  make sure you set `userInteractionEnabled = true` for your popup menu class, then you override the touch in this class to handle all nodes  inside of it

Comment: SKS Builder in xcode 8.0 is still buggy.  If you find your code in your custom class is not being called check the custom class again.  For me when first creating the sks file, the custom class is not being saved every time.

Comment: @fawsha1 you need to make sure you leave the box so that auto save kicks in, or hit option + s

Answer (score 3):

If you want your game works well, the first thing to do is to make sure that, when you pass to a new scene, the previous scene is deallocated.
I think you can construct a common menu or a common menu button to a custom class and call it anywhere you want:

```
class MenuButton : SKSpriteNode
{
    var length: CGFloat!

    override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: SKColor!, size: CGSize) {
        self.length = 50 // default lenght
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }

    convenience init(color: SKColor, length: CGFloat = 50) {
        var size = CGSize(width: length, height: length);
        self.init(texture:nil, color: color, size: size)
        self.length = length
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // Decoding length here would be nice...
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: What I mean is that you can create a custom class (a new file) for your MenuButton inheriting SKSpriteNode methods, so the next time you want your custom button simply you call let myBtn = MenuButton.init(...)

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano,  I am not sure if this answers the question.  You are just talking about how to check the code to ensure deallocation, and showing code on how to make a subclass

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Are you kidding me? This is a natural way to make a customization, there are several ways, this is one of them. Im not here to do work on commissions, but to give advices and illustrate methods to find the right way. Your answer is another method I dont like because I think is not easy to customize in deep as the nude code can do, but it could work.

Comment: The question is "how to add an SKSpriteNode to a scene from another class?"  At what point do you answer that question

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano, SKReferenceNodes offer as much customization as you can possibly imagine, so no idea where you got that idea from.  Try using them, you will grow to love them.